# Is it possible to get the original code from react-scripts uglify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uglifyjs, react-scripts

I have a react application deployed without source maps. I'm using react-scripts instead of having ejected and configure the build from scratch.
My question is, is this safe enough to prevent from somebody steal my original code?
Should I eject and use another uglify/obfuscate library?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Uglify -- like any other minifier -- has nothing to do with preventing theft of your code. Minifiers make the code smaller, and have a side effect of being *harder for humans* to read, but the functionality is exactly the same. There is **absolutely nothing** that prevents someone from reverse-engineering Javascript executed in their browser. When a user "visits" your site, it's really just a download where you're essentially saying, "here, have the code for this application so you can run it".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But minifying/uglifying is safe 'enough'. JavaScript files inevitably show off everything in browser-side, so we cannot hide source code perfectly. obfuscating library may slower your codes.
Just keep in mind that you should not include secret keys in your JavaScript code.